# How to use custom video stream for a-frame AR

Tags: video-streaming, augmented-reality, aframe

I am playing around aframe-ar, and noticed that it uses webcam by default.
I would like to use another stream.
Approximately architecture would be
NodeJS app, that captures video from webcam, connected to PC where it is running -> WebSocket connection, which sends stream from this webcam to client -> augmenting this stream on client.

I would like to analyze video stream with computer vision methods before sending it to client (which uses react-aframe-ar wrapper).

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes this is possible. Take a look at the https://github.com/networked-aframe/networked-aframe project. I haven't played with it in some time but I managed a hacky prototype of video streaming (might be in my fork, not sure) via webRTC so I'd guess someone has implemented for real by now.

Comment: Thanks! Let's take a look.